# Java InputStream skips data

Tags: java, io, serial-port, inputstream, rxtx

I want to read data from serial port using the RXTX libary. This works fine so far. I've got a event listener, which executes when data of the InputStream is avalaible.

**The Problem:** The InputStream skips some bytes every few hundred bytes. I thought I found a solution by creating an BufferedInputStream. Now, data is lost much more rarely, but it still happens sometimes.

**Serial Port Params:**
Baudrate: 921600, 
Data bits: 8,
Parity: none,
Stop bits: 1,
Handshake: none

I need 100% complete data. How can I ensure this in Java?

Comment: do you use UDP as a protocoll or TCP. TCP is a safe connection. As your "Handshake"-Parameter says none I conclude that youre not using TCP.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what this means. I know the theoretical definition of UDP and TCP, but I I've got no idea how to implement TCP in my application.

Comment: No other advises?

Comment: I'am not very knowlagable about serials nor the RXTX libary. Another possibility of data loss could be your outputstream (not sure if you got one 0.0). The outputstream must be flushed. There are cases were the data-packages are to small to be send therefore you have to flush your outputstream